# Can you get all Chaos Emeralds without completing every level?

Tags: sega-genesis, sonic-the-hedgehog

Can you do this, perhaps via the level select code?

Or must you complete the whole game again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the 6 Emeralds in the first 6 Acts you play, you have in total 10 chances to get them. The important thing is that you collect them before Scrap Brain Zone, because there's no access to Special Stage there. Here is an example video:

Each zone before Scrap Brain Zone has one color of emerald. He gets the last Emerald on Star Light Zone 2, before completing Star Light Zone 3 and the whole Scrap Brain Zone.

Comment: I've worked it out. Each zone before Scrap Brain Zone has one colour of emerald. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't get access to the Special Stage in boss acts, so you have to play _at least_ the first 8 acts to get the 6 emeralds

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick I remember from my childhood that relies on the fact that **you keep emeralds upon resetting the Genesis.**

1. Use the level select code (up down left right A+start).
2. Choose the special stage and get an emerald (or fail).
3. When the first level starts, reset the Genesis using the Reset button.
4. Repeat the above process until you have all the emeralds.
5. Use the level select code again to choose any level you want.

You'll then start the level you chose, and you'll still have all of the emeralds you acquired. [This cheat guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gen-cheats/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_1991_Cheats) confirms my memory.